# Implement 64bit Left Rotation in C using 8bit controller

Tags: c

I want to do left circular rotation for 64bit variables but my controller only operates in 8-bit, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Is it constant-distance or variable-distance rotation? If constant, what rotation distances do you need?

Comment: Do you have a `uint64_t` type? (by including stdint.h)

Comment: uint64_t x;
    unsigned shift;  // shift must be between 1 and 63 inclusive
    x = (x << shift) | (x >> (64-shift));

Comment: @chux There is no `uint64_t` in a 8-bit controller.

Comment: @nightcracker: How do you know? Whether there is `uint64_t` in the given implementation depends on the implementation and only on implementation. The "bitness" of the hardware is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @AndreyT Surely the implementation _may_ provide emulation for the `uint64_t` type, but if you know your target platform is 8-bit I would try to avoid it at all costs.

Comment: @nightcracker: That just doesn't make sense. The very statement of the problem in this case is to emulate one specific operation on 64-bit type. So, the question is whether it is better to use the *compiler-provided* emulation, or implement one *manually* using C language features. In most cases the compiler-provided emulation will be more efficient than manually implemented one (unless you are dealing with a very poorly implemented compiler).

Comment: @AndreyT I worry more about portability than performance in this case. Having to re-write the code because another compiler suddenly doesn't support `uint64_t` sucks.

Comment: @nightcracker: Oh, I see. I'm sorry if I was rude in my previous comment. I was focusing solely on efficiency. But from the portability point of view (if that's an issue) it does indeed make sense to avoid emulated types.

Comment: @nightcracker There are certainly `uint64_t` in 8-bit controllers.  Been using such in PIC controllers for years.  32-bit types in 8-bit processors have been available for over 4 decades.  The types supported by a compiler are independent, though often related, to the native types of the processor.  Your years of experience may be better than the optimizations available by a compiler, but I'll readily use a compiler's uint64_t anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes the 64-bit variable is little-endian. Modifies it in-place.

```
void rol(unsigned char a[8], int b){
    unsigned char c[8];
    unsigned char t, u;
    int i, j;

    /* Clamp b to [0, 63] */
    b &= 63;

    /* First rotate by 0 to 7 whole bytes (0 to 56 bits in multiples of 8) */
    for(i=0, j=b/8;i<8;i++){
        c[j] = a[i];

        j++;
        j &= 7;
    }

    /* Second, rotate by 0 to 7 bits, depending on what's left */
    b &= 7;

    if(b){/* Shift by 1 to 7 bits using bitwise ops into output */
        for(i=0, j=7;i<8;i++){
            u = c[i] << (b);
            t = c[j] >> (8-b);

            a[i] = u | t;

            j++;
            j &= 7;
        }
    }else{/* Shift by 0 bits = copy into output */
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            a[i] = c[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is possible to do so. It is just a question of how efficient it has to be.

Rotation by 1 bit can be implemented trivially, by shifting the bytes sequentially, inspecting the bit that "shifts out" from each 8-bit byte and carrying it over to the next 8-bit byte.

Rotation by `n` bits can be implemented in "dumb" fashion by performing a sequence of `n` 1-bit rotations.

A less "dumb" approach would be to perform circular reassignment (rotation) of the entire bytes `n / 8` times, and then finishing it with `n % 8` sequential 1-bit rotations. I.e. a 19 bit rotation = 2 full-byte rotations followed by 3 1-bit rotations.

You might also observe that in 64-bit word rotation left by 63 bits is the same as rotation right by 1 bit, meaning that if you have both left and right circular rotations at your disposal, then you should never have to rotate by more than 32 bits.

If the target word size is limited by 64 bits, then this might be sufficient already.